# How to do prepared statement in Yii1?

Tags: sql, yii, prepared-statement

Ho do I convert this query to prepared

```
Booking::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('is_deleted'=>NOTDELETED,'status'=>BOOKINGSTATUSPENDING,'payment_status'=>UNPAIDBOOKINGSTATUS,'transaction_status'=>FAILEDPAYMENTTRANSACTION),array('order'=>'id DESC', 'limit'=>DASHBOARDVIEWRECORDCOUNT));
```

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: some tools shown that there is SQL injunction attack possible at this location so i want to convert it to prepared statement for prevention

Comment: Could you explain what are NOTDELETED, BOOKINGSTATUSPENDING .. and so on ? ... are not php var .. so these are constants ?

Comment: yes those are constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many solution i have found way for that

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition ='status=:status AND payment_status=:payment_status AND transaction_status=:transaction_status ';
$criteria->params = array(':status'=>BOOKINGSTATUSPENDING,':payment_status'=>UNPAIDBOOKINGSTATUS,':transaction_status'=>FAILEDPAYMENTTRANSACTION);
$criteria->limit= DASHBOARDVIEWRECORDCOUNT;
$criteria->order = 'id DESC';
$incompleteBooking = Booking::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('is_deleted'=>NOTDELETED),$criteria);
```